# How can I retrieve the subnets in a given VPC with Terraform?

Tags: types, terraform, subnet, vpc

I was trying to retrieve the subnets in a given VPC, in my case the default VPC, however I keep getting an error:

```
data "aws_vpc" "default_vpc" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id
}

output "subnets_out" {
  value = data.aws_subnet.subnets
}
```

> Error: multiple EC2 Subnets matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single EC2 Subnet

The first data call works, I get my default VPC id, however the second one fails.

Originally I had 1 subnet in my default VPC and at that time, the second data call worked too but to my surprise it returned the subnet as a map instead of a map within a set. So I was curious what would happen if there was more than one subnets in my VPC but then the data call failed.

What I find really confusing is that the [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnets) says:

> This resource can be useful for getting back a **set** of subnet ID**s**.

If it's supposed to return a set of subnet IDs, then why is it an issue that multiple subnets were matched?

Comment: Are you trying to use `subnets_out` somewhere afterwards?

Comment: I was trying to use the data.subnets only, so that wasn't the issue but @ChrisDoyle crack the source of the problem which was apparently a typo (I used aws_subnet instead of aws_subnets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aws_subnet` is a resource for a specific subnet. Its not for a collection of subnets. so when you pass the VPC_ID, aws is finding more than one subnet in that VPC. Its not possible to store more than one subnets in `aws_subnet`

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet

> aws_subnet provides details about a specific VPC subnet.

It sounds like you should be using `aws_subnets` https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnets

> This resource can be useful for getting back a set of subnet IDs.

This will return you a list of subnet ID's which you can then use in a foreach in `aws_subnet` to get the specific details of each subnet

Comment: Thank you, apparently I just left the 's' accidentally. Makes perfect sense now.